# Jquery manage local script with full ajax site

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically my app work like that :

Index.php manage call to other pages.

Each page contains 2 function onLoad() and onClose() which are redefined in each page

Index.php call the pages and execute the onLoad

Basically, i preload the page in a hidden div, i execute the predefined $.onLoad function and the i put the loaded content into a visible div

**My question is only about the onLoad() scope, i want to remove code from the jquery eval seq when i change page, but i need a way to define it in the page.php file without knowing the container**

The eval/seq is probably the eval queue of jquery, can't found info about that, just obtain with firebug...

*In 2 words, i would like to be able to remove injected dom and script when i change context (pages)*

index.php

```
$.onLoad = function() {}



$("#blabla").onChange(function() {
     $("#data_iframe").load(chaineUrl, {}, function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
         $("#data_iframe").ready(function() {
              $("#data_div").children().remove();
               $.onLoad();
              $("#data_iframe").children().hide().appendTo($("#data_div")).show();          $("#data_iframe").children().remove();
              $.onLoad = undefined; 
          }
     });
});
```

page.php

```
<script>
    $.onClose = (function(){
        $('#container').blablabla();
        //alert("test");
    });
    $.onLoad = (function(){
    $('#container').blablabla();
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that the jquery EVAL/SEQ keep growing each time a page is opened
and there are some side-effect like calling multiple time a function...

I guess its a scope problem so can you help me correct my code
(i've try with or without the $ but doesn't change anything)
just for information

```
    <div id="data_div"></div>
<div id="data_iframe"></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Umm, jQuery doesn't evaluate SQL. Why did you mention SQL? Care to give more detail?

Comment: SOrry hehe EVAL/SEQ not SQL, (seeing in firebug)

Comment: You still haven't provided enough info for anyone to help you. Can you link to an example?

Comment: i guess when i use jquery load function it eval the script inside my page, is it possible to remove evaluated script ?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use $(document).ready instead of onload. No need to do the "onload" trigger in load complete function. The ready function within the page.php will do the same job.
And how about direct load into data_div?

index.php

```
$("#blabla").onChange(function() {
   $("#data_div").load(page.php);
});
```

page.php

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#container').blablabla();
    });
</script>
```

I didn't try page close function before, may be it is not what you want. But you can try:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#container').blablabla();
       $(window).unbind('unload');
       $(window).unload(function(){
           $('#container').blablabla();
           //alert("test");
       })   
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, i've maybe overheaded my solution ... I think that my problem is more about the way the script is kept in the DOM even after changing page... i don't know why but it seem that the EVAL js is just never disposed until the main page is reloaded